# URL routing for domains

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, .htaccess, lamp

I have a site with 10's of thousands of users.  Each user has their own site hosted by me at a subdomain of mysite.com/user1 or as an add on domain at user1.mysite.com or user1.com.  This is all done in pure LAMP stack.

When I first started out each user needed custom modifications to their site so I made separate directories for each user.  I stopped making these custom modifications a while ago and now I have thousands of directories all with the same exact php scripts.  The only difference between these directories is one file with the user's ID - that I use to grab their customization options from my database.

In order to consolidate my code I want to create a .htaccess rule that appropriates part of the url (if url requested is mysite.com/user get user1, if it is user2.mysite.com grab user2, if it is user3.com grab user3)  and pass it to a php script that will call my database and return the user ID that matches that domain.  I can then pass that ID to a common scripts directory which can take care of everything else.  The downside to this is that now I have to make an additional query for every single request.

Is making a database call for every request putting too much load on my database?
Is this how other sites like facebook, or linkedin do this?  When I access myname.facebook.com is there a database call before my page is served.
Is there a better strategy?

Comment: I think you can use some deduplication filesystem (btrfs or sdfs). The CPU cycles are not used to serve pages and saves space!

Comment: Since the lookups are fairly static and simple key-value combos you can use something to cache the lookups in ram. An example is memcached.